# Changing the the visibility of a child component after rendering started

Tags: html, wicket

I have a component which consists of two children component A and B. However, the visibility of showing either A or B can only be determined after the page rendering started. I tried to do this but got back the following error:

```
Cannot modify component hierarchy after render phase has started
```

So, is there any way to change the visibility of the children components in my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure if I understand your problem.
I assume that you have 2 containers and want to display only one of them. If that is the case you can simply extend the `onConfigure()` method and change the visibility the way you want it to. This method will be called once during each rendering and is therefore preferred over extending the `isVisible()` method (which is called multiple times during each request).

```
private IModel<Boolean> switchModel = Model.of(Boolean.FALSE);

@Override
protected void onInitialize() {
    super.onInitialize();

    WebMarkupContainer container1 = new WebMarkupContainer("container1") {
        @Override
        protected void onConfigure() {
            super.onConfigure();
            setVisible(Boolean.TRUE.equals(switchModel.getModelObject()));
        }
    };
    add(container1);

    WebMarkupContainer container2 = new WebMarkupContainer("container2") {
        @Override
        protected void onConfigure() {
            super.onConfigure();
            setVisible(Boolean.FALSE.equals(switchModel.getModelObject()));
        }
    };
    add(container2);
}
```